# Flex SQLite optimization: adding database name in front of tables

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, micro-optimization

This article on Livedocs says you should add the database name in front of tables.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d47.html

My question is, should I do that everywhere where a table name appears or only once?

In this query:
`select T1.col,T2.col from T1 left join T2 on T1.id=T2.id order by T2.order;`

Should I add `main.T1` and `main.T2` everywhere or just after for, the first time:
`select T1.col,T2.col from main.T1 left join main.T2 on T1.id=T2.id order by T2.order;`

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like super micro optimizations, I would just avoid it.

Comment: If it's mentioned on that page it's probably worth it, especially on a mobile device. They say AIR will look for available databases then pick `main`. One query less sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a reading of the documentation you cited, I'd say it advises you to use the database name in the FROM clause only:

> Always explicitly specify database names along with table names in a
>   statement. (Use “main” if it’s the main database). For example, use
>   **SELECT employeeId FROM main.employees** rather than SELECT employeeId
>   FROM employees. Explicitly specifying the database name prevents the
>   runtime from having to check each database to find the matching table.

[emphasis added]

Comment: Yeah, but that's a simplistic example. If I have joins, and need to specify `table.column` before select do I use main there as well? How about in join statements when a table name can be used multiple times? I hate unclear documentation...